# MVC actionlink parameter never sending

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink, html.actionlink

Can anyone tell me why my parameters in the following code are always null when the controller action is called:

```
<% foreach (var row in Model) { %>
     <tr>
        <td><%=Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Customer", new { controller = "Customer", action = "Edit", id = row.CustomerID })%>|
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Sales", "List", "Sale", new { controller = "Sale", action = "List", id = row.CustomerID }, null)%></td>
        <td><%= Html.Encode(row.CustomerID)%> </td>
        <td><%= Html.Encode(row.FirstName)%> </td>
        <td><%= Html.Encode(row.LastName)%> </td>
        <td><%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:g}", row.DateOfBirth))%></td>
        <td><%= Html.Encode(row.Address)%> </td>
        <td><%= Html.Encode(row.Phone)%> </td>
    </tr>



<% } %>
```

Controller code:

```
public class SaleController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult List(int CustomerID)
    {
        SaleListModel SaleList = SaleServices.GetList(CustomerID);
        return View(SaleList);
    }

}
```

Comment: both of the action links send the parameter as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a parameter named `id`, but your controller actions are looking for a parameter named `CustomerID`.  These need to match.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Marked your answer as correct since you were first.

Answer (score 2):

Action parameters are bound *by name*, not by position or type. Therefore you should change `id` to `CustomerID` in your calls to `Html.ActionLink`:

```
    <td><%=Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Customer", new { controller = "Customer", action = "Edit", CustomerID = row.CustomerID })%>|
        <%= Html.ActionLink("Sales", "List", "Sale", new { controller = "Sale", action = "List", CustomerID = row.CustomerID }, null)%></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following instead. You're specifying parameters (Controller/Action) that aren't necessary.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Customer", new { id = row.CustomerID })%>|
<%= Html.ActionLink("Sales", "List", "Sale", new { id = row.CustomerID })%>
```

Comment: For some reason with your code the Edit customer link still sends a null for the parameter and the Sale list link sends null for the parameter but links to the list action in the customer controller rather than the sale controller

Comment: just saw your edit, you named the parameter incorrectly — but it looks like someone else got to it before me. oh well, bills before thrills ...